# Return just the number when using the np.divide function with dtype:float64

Tags: python, django, pandas, numpy, divide

I have created a class object that retrieves information from a database and stores it in pandas so I can use some data science library's for manipulation.

```
class IntDailyGoals (object):
    def __init__(self, begin_date, end_date, store=None):
        self.begin_date = begin_date
        self.end_date = end_date
        self.store = store
        self.int_mnth_goal = pd.DataFrame(list(StoreGoalsInput.objects.values('store_number',
                                                                              'interest',
                                                                              'date')))
        self.int_mnth_goal['interest'] = pd.to_numeric(self.int_mnth_goal['interest'])
        self.int_mnth_goal['date'] = pd.to_datetime(self.int_mnth_goal['date'])
        self.mnth_goal_int =self.int_mnth_goal[(self.int_mnth_goal['date'] >= self.begin_date) &
                                               (self.int_mnth_goal['date'] <= self.end_date) &
                                               (self.int_mnth_goal['store_number'] == self.store.store_number)]
        self.mnth_goal_int= self.mnth_goal_int['interest']
        self.tot_workingdays = np.busday_count(np.datetime64(self.begin_date),
                                               np.datetime64(self.end_date),
                                               weekmask='Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat')
        self.div_intmnthgoal_workingdays = round(np.divide(self.mnth_goal_int, self.tot_workingdays),2)


    def get_div_goalsint_wdays(self):
        div_goalsint_wdays = self.div_intmnthgoal_workingdays
        return div_goalsint_wdays

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_div_goalsint_wdays()
```

This returns:

```
2    6558.4 
Name: interest, dtype: float64
```

I just need it to return the integer `6558.4` as this is being displayed in a Django template.

I have tried this:

```
    def get_div_goalsint_wdays(self):
    div_goalsint_wdays = self.div_intmnthgoal_workingdays['interest']
    return div_goalsint_wdays
```

but I get a `KeyError: 'interest'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you describe is a pandas Series with a single value.
To get the float value it contains, you should use:

```
self.div_intmnthgoal_workingdays.iloc[0]
```

Comment: Adrien Matissart, thanks! I need to further my understanding on the .iloc as I move forward in my learning. You suggestion has definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: `iloc` is for integer-location based indexing (from 0 to length-1). See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html?highlight=iloc#pandas.Series.iloc

Comment: Thanks again! I remember briefly going over this during the data science course I took. I believe part of my problem is everything has been theory up till now. This is progress to see it used in this way so I am thankful for you and the others help!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values (without index) by using the `.values` property or the `.tolist` method.

For example if I have this `Series`:

```
>>> s
2    3
dtype: int64
```

then the values are:

```
>>> s.values
array([3], dtype=int64)
>>> s.tolist()
[3]
```

This can be indexed like any other sequence-like class:

```
>>> s.values[0]
3
>>> s.tolist()[0]
3
```